# Using a class instance in multiple pages PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, instance

I have two php pages and I want to use an instance of a class used in one page to another page.

My first page looks like this...

```
class test {

 public $cfd_name;

 function __construct($value) {

        $this->cfd_name = $value;
 }

}

$_SESSION['cc_test'] = new test('Joe');
```

and my second page looks like this

```
echo $_SESSION['cc_test']->cfd_name;
```

but nothing is being echoed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this is the usual clarification for this kind of question: `do you have session_start();`

Comment: you want to use the same instance in two different page? even when you reload these pages? am I right?

Comment: Yeah @Ghost I have session_start(); in both pages.

Comment: @rogelio yup. same instance in two different pages or more even when you reload the pages.

Comment: so, you need to serialize the object first, then save into a session

Answer (score 1):

I thing a simple way is serializing the object,take a look

```
//includes, codes, session_start, etc...
$test = new test('Joe');
$_SESSION['cc_test'] = serialize($test);
```

then, in your other page you can access the object doing

```
$test = unserialize($_SESSION['cc_test']);
$test->cfd_name;
```

More info about `serialize`, [here](https://www.php.net/serialize)

Answer (score 0):

In case your class is in first file is this:

```
class test {

 public $cfd_name;

 function __construct($value) {

        $this->cfd_name = $value;
 }

}
```

Just use `include(file1.php)` in second file
and then declare this in the second file.

```
session_start();
$test = new test;
$_SESSION['cc_test'] = $test0->cfd_name;
echo $_SESSION['cc_test'];
```

Comment: this code is only storing an attribute in a session var. He needs access an object(the same instance) from any page